# Use regex to parse chess algebraic notation

Tags: regex

**tl;dr**

I am looking for a regex that only matches the following strings:

- An empty string
- `+`
- `(=)`
- `+ (=)`
- `#`

---

**Motivation:**

In chess, a move can (among other things) be a check or a check mate. As long as it is not a check mate, a player can offer a draw to their opponent after making a move.

I am making a toy project which parses chess games written following FIDE's rules; they specify that the following suffixes are used to indicate the previous possibilities:

- A check is indicated by `+`;
- A check mate is indicated by `#`;
- A draw offer is represented by `(=)`.

So the following are the only valid suffixed:

- (nothing: the move is not a check, and the player is not offering a draw).
- `(=)` (no check; a draw is offered)
- `+` (check; no draw offered)..
- `+ (=)` (check; a draw is offered).
- `#` (check mate; no draw can be offered since the game is over).

I am struggling to turn this into a regex. I want to express:

`("+" (0 or 1 times) followed by "(=)" (0 or 1 times)) or ("#" (0 or 1 times))`

I have made several attempts but all of them fail. In the spirit of showing my work I am adding this one, but it is probably garbage:
`((\+{0,1}|(\+ (=)){0,1})|#){0,1}`

Comment: Some specific examples of strings you want to match would help. The final `or ("#" (0 or 1 times))` seems to imply that an empty match ("match # 0 times") would be acceptable, is that right? Seems a bit odd

Comment: Why the chess lesson ? Call Kasparov.

Comment: I have added a tl;dr.

Comment: Just make an alternation list like the one I posted, change it as needed. If you are not matching sub-strings, put a couple of anchors around it and enclose it in a group `^(?:...)$`. Change the `([ ])` to just `()`  to match form, but keep it in there. Any questions, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

These are your options in terms of groups matching as being *flags*.

`([ ])|(\(=\))|(\+)(?!\(=\))|(\+\(=\))|(\#)`

Explained

```
   ( [ ] )               # (1), (nothing: the move is not a check, and the player is not offering a draw).
|  
   ( \(=\) )             # (2), (no check; a draw is offered)
|  
   ( \+ )                # (3), (check; no draw offered)
   (?! \(=\) )
|  
   (                     # (4 start), (check; a draw is offered).
        \+
        \(=\)
   )                     # (4 end)
|  
   ( \# )                # (5), (check mate; no draw can be offered since the game is over).
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a possibility:

`((\+{0,1}( \(=\)){0,1})|#{0,1})`

Explained:

```
(
 (\+{0,1}           # A plus sign at most 1 time...
 ( \(=\)){0,1})     # Followed by "(=)" at most 1 time
|                   # ... or ...
 #{0,1}             # A hash sign at most 1 time
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Only checkmate is a special case, the other two (check, draw) can be combined with each being optional:

[`^(#|\+?(\(=\))?)$`](https://regex101.com/r/KLoWq5/1)